# Setting the icon size of items in QComboBox in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have been trying to build a custom combobox for selecting a linestyle type in my plotting GUI. The dropdown menu contains previews of the linestyle, for example solid, dashed, dotted lines.

I have been able to adjust the size of the selected line, by setting the icon size of the combobox

```
mycombobox.setIconSize(QSize(75, 25))
```

But this does not seem to affect the QListView inside of the QComboBox when I click on the dropdown arrow to bring up the dropdown menu.

[image]

[image]

Above you can see that the selected line type scales up properly when it is selected, however while the drop down menu is in use, the icons displayed there are not the correct size. I cannot figure out how to alter their size without altering the actual size of the image file.

Below is the code for my custom QComboBox. I would like to figure out how I can alter the size of the icons in the drop down menu. I imagine I have to alter some subcontrol of the QListView, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Does anybody know how to do this?

```
self.fitstyle_linestyle_cbox = QComboBox()
self.fitstyle_linestyle_cbox.setObjectName('linestylecbox')
self.fitstyle_linestyle_cbox.setFixedSize(75, 25)
self.linestyle_cbox_item_solid = QPixmap(str(self.dotgui_path) + '/DotGUI/GUIassets/linestyle_edit_solid.png')
self.linestyle_cbox_item_dashed = QPixmap(str(self.dotgui_path) + '/DotGUI/GUIassets/linestyle_edit.png')
self.linestyle_cbox_item_dotted = QPixmap(str(self.dotgui_path) + '/DotGUI/GUIassets/linestyle_edit_dotted.png')
self.fitstyle_linestyle_cbox.addItem(QIcon(self.linestyle_cbox_item_solid), '')
self.fitstyle_linestyle_cbox.addItem(QIcon(self.linestyle_cbox_item_dashed), '')
self.fitstyle_linestyle_cbox.addItem(QIcon(self.linestyle_cbox_item_dotted), '')
self.fitstyle_linestyle_cbox.setIconSize(QSize(75, 25))
self.fitstyle_linestyle_cbox.setStyleSheet('''
    QComboBox#linestylecbox 
        {
            background-color: ''' + GlobalVars.color_bkgnd_dark + ''';
            color: ''' + GlobalVars.color_text_dark + ''';
            font: 10px Lucida Sans;
            border: 0px solid ''' + GlobalVars.color_bkgnd_dark + ''';
            margin: 0px;
        }

    QComboBox#linestylecbox::drop-down 
        {
            border: 0px;
            border-top: 0px;
            border-color: ''' + GlobalVars.color_bkgnd_dark + ''';
            background-color: ''' + GlobalVars.color_bkgnd_dark + ''';
            font: 10px Lucida Sans;
        }

    QComboBox#linestylecbox::down-arrow 
        {
            image: url( ''' + str(self.dotgui_path) + '''/DotGUI/GUIassets/down-arrow.png);
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            border: 0px;
        }

    QListView
        {
            background-color: ''' + GlobalVars.color_bkgnd_light + ''';
        }
    ''')
```